# Write a function that takes two parameters, word and n, as arguments and returns the word multiple times like this ‘HelloHelloHello’

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

im suppose to return the word concatenated into itself n number of times it keeps coming out as nan I don't know what im doing wrong  . the word is supposed to print to the console like this HelloHelloHello’ if I pass in Hello and the number 3.

```
function pere(word ,n) {
    return  word * n  ;
 
}

console.log (pere("hello", 3));

function pere(word ,n) {
    return  word * n  ;
 
}

console.log (pere("hello", 3));

function pere(word ,n) {
    return  (word * n)  ;
 
}

console.log ((hello)(3));
```

Comment: Javascript != python! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```js
function pere(word, n){
  console.log(word.repeat(n));
}
```